# Elasticsearch - Or-filter on optional fields

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, filter, search-engine

I am kind of new to Elasticsearch. Here is my request :

```
{
    filter: {
       or: [
           {regexp: {foo: 'sameRegexpString'}},
           {regexp: {bar: 'sameRegexpString'}}
       ]
    }
    size: 200,
    _source: true
}
```

I expect to get all documents with a `foo` or a `bar` field matching my regexp.

My problem is that not all documents have a `bar` field, it is optional. So the request returns only documents that have a `bar` field (and which matches the regexp). The documents without a `bar` fields are ignored or filtered...

How can I get what I expect?

For the record, this or-filter sample only contains 2 fields, but I got around 15-20 of them and at least half of them are optionals.

Thx.

---

For instance, let's take these two documents :

`{ foo:'baz', bar:'foobar', other:'noop'}`
and 
`{ foo:'foobaz', other:'noop again'}`

If I look for `foo.*` regexp, it only comes up with the first one.
Same result if I look for `.*baz`...
As long as the `bar` field is missing, the second document is always ignored.

For the record I am using version 1.2 of elasticsearch (and I cannot update it).

Comment: could you give an example regexp and  document it fails for , it works for me

Comment: @keety, I added an example to my post. Maybe the version of my elasticsearch is too outdated. What's yours ?

Comment: tested and worked in version  `es 1.6.1`